# Is it possible to show a diffraction caustic as a home experiment / lecture demonstration?

Tags: optics, mathematical-physics, home-experiment

[This nice paper](http://www.pnas.org/content/93/6/2614.long) contains a neat demonstration of the fact that optical caustics, when seen from a wave-optics perspective, contain a bunch of interesting interference terms which can be calculated nicely using the integrals with coalescing saddles of catastrophe theory. Moreover, they showcase this with experiments that have clear optical implementations of those functions, which reportedly look much like this:

[image]

<sup>[Image source](https://michaelberryphysics.wordpress.com/2013/07/23/672/)</sup>

**I would like to be able to reproduce this sort of behaviour**, as a home experiment and as a lecture demonstration, ideally in a configuration that doesn't require anything much fancier than a laser pointer and some household items or office equipment, and ideally in a procedure that is simple, robust, stable, and easily reproducible. It doesn't have to be all that clean ─ it just has to reliably produce images with the Airy fringes and the [Pearcey-like behaviour](http://dlmf.nist.gov/36.3.F1.mag) at the tips of the caustics.

What are good ways to do this, or good resources that explain the procedure?

Comment: a white porcelain cup and a laser pointer, the caustic is a nephroid

Comment: @hyportnex I had a go with a porcelain cup and a laser pointer but failed to get the fringes. Any practical tips?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This may be easier than you think. I took this photo (with my iPhone) of a cusp caustic which I generated by darkening the bathroom, wetting the mirror, and angling the laser pointer so it hit a water drop and then reflected off the mirror onto a convenient spot on the wall:

[image]

It's extremely close to the Pearcey integral.

The wall was literally covered in these things. Here's a shot zoomed out slightly so you can see the spidery networks connecting the cusps:

[image]

Here is a diagram of the "apparatus":
[image]

Comment: I was gonna down vote you for stealing this from Wikipedia, but I of course checked the references first.

Comment: @JEB :-) AFAICT There isn't a lot of interest in this stuff so the same names tend to pop up.

Comment: Which Wikipedia page is this?

Comment: @EmilioPisanty https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearcey_integral

Answer (score 1):

To add to Dan's answer - if the purpose is just to observe these effects rather than recreate them "in a lab", then you can do pretty much the experiment Dan suggests without any lasers or dark rooms by instead looking at distant city lights at night through a water drop on glasses (or plastic, or glass plate, or...). The more irregular the droplet is - the more cusps (the pointy "angles" in your picture) will be visible on the smudge that the light becomes when seen through a droplet. The more point-like is the light (ideally - phone flash light in the dark) - the clearer the interference stripes near caustics and cusps will be.